# Is it possible to add an external credential file to Docker build context when using Jenkins with Git?

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, dockerfile, devops

I'm trying to setup an automated build with Git > Jenkins > Docker.
The Dockerfile gets pulled, but fails due to a missing credential file:

```
    ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker- 
    builder103029254/creds.json: no such file or directory
```

The file will be used to login into the database.
Since it's a sensitive file, I don't want it in my github.

The build context changes with every build process so I'm not able to provide this file from local storage.

I tried adding additonal arguments with the docker build command and changing the WORKDIR, but nothing worked.

How do I add this file to the docker build context?

Comment: Is you cread.json file is static and need to be used in every build while building containers ??

Comment: Are you sure you need this file at build time? I can't see why you would need credentials only to build. Even if you find some magic way to add it, it will be in your image for everybody to see and I guess you don't want that either. Can you post your full Dockerfile and the commands you tried?